Cannot memory-free strings from arbitrary-length array of strings
I want to write a function that will read a text file, and return its lines as an array of strings for further processing.
To this end, I am trying to get my head around correctly handling an N-length array of strings, for N determined at runtime.
I had this basic example with a hard-coded array of length two. It runs fine, and does not report any leaks:
const std = @import("std");
const stdout = std.io.getStdOut().writer();
var gpa = std.heap.GeneralPurposeAllocator(.{}){};

pub fn main() !void {
    const alloc = gpa.allocator();
    defer _ = gpa.deinit();

    const names = try getNames(alloc);
    defer destroyNames(alloc, names);

    for(names) |name| {
        try stdout.print("Hello {s}\n", .{name});
    }
}


fn destroyNames(alloc:std.mem.Allocator, names:*[2][]const u8) void {
    for(names) |name| {
        // Correctly frees the '[]const u8'
        alloc.free(name);
    }
    _ = alloc.destroy(names);
}


fn getNames(alloc:std.mem.Allocator) !*[2][]const u8 {
    const names = [_][]const u8{"Alix", "Bub"};

    const new_names = try alloc.create([2][]const u8);
    const title = "Prof";

    for(names, 0..) |name, i| {
        new_names[i] = try std.fmt.allocPrint(alloc, "{s} {s}", .{title, name} );
    }

    return new_names;
}

Satisfied with this, I proceeded to move just a couple of things around. The following runs, but fails on the deferred destroyNames operation
const std = @import("std");
const stdout = std.io.getStdOut().writer();
var gpa = std.heap.GeneralPurposeAllocator(.{}){};

pub fn main() !void {
    const alloc = gpa.allocator();
    defer _ = gpa.deinit();

    const names = try getNames(alloc);
    defer destroyNames(alloc, names);

    for(names.*) |name| {
        try stdout.print("Hello {s}\n", .{name});
    }
}


fn destroyNames(alloc:std.mem.Allocator, names:*[][]const u8) void {
    for(names.*) |name| {
        // ERROR - core dumps here...!
        // Cannot properly free a '[]const u8' supplied like this
        alloc.free(name);
    }
    _ = alloc.destroy(names);
}


fn getNames(alloc:std.mem.Allocator) !*[][]const u8 {
    // Stand-in. Hypothetically, read from a N-line file...
    const names = [_][]const u8{"Alix", "Bub"};

    var new_names:[][]const u8 = undefined;
    new_names = try alloc.create([names.len][]const u8);
    const title = "Prof";

    for(names, 0..) |name, i| {
        new_names[i] = try std.fmt.allocPrint(alloc, "{s} {s}", .{title, name} );
    }

    return &new_names;
}

Running results in
$ zig run length-general.zig 
Hello Prof Alix
Hello Prof Bub
General protection exception (no address available)
/home/tai/.local/var/zig/zig-linux-x86_64-0.14.0-dev.1366+d997ddaa1/lib/compiler_rt/memset.zig:19:14: 0x10f7f10 in memset (compiler_rt)
            d[0] = c;
             ^
/home/tai/.local/var/zig/zig-linux-x86_64-0.14.0-dev.1366+d997ddaa1/lib/std/mem/Allocator.zig:313:26: 0x1040e57 in free__anon_3449 (length-general)
    @memset(non_const_ptr[0..bytes_len], undefined);
                         ^
/home/tai/scratch-zig/length-general.zig:26:19: 0x103bacc in destroyNames (length-general)
        alloc.free(name);
                  ^
/home/tai/scratch-zig/length-general.zig:14:23: 0x103b59c in main (length-general)
    defer destroyNames(alloc, names);
                      ^
/home/tai/.local/var/zig/zig-linux-x86_64-0.14.0-dev.1366+d997ddaa1/lib/std/start.zig:615:37: 0x103ad2f in posixCallMainAndExit (length-general)
            const result = root.main() catch |err| {
                                    ^
/home/tai/.local/var/zig/zig-linux-x86_64-0.14.0-dev.1366+d997ddaa1/lib/std/start.zig:250:5: 0x103a90f in _start (length-general)
    asm volatile (switch (native_arch) {
    ^
???:?:?: 0x0 in ??? (???)
Aborted (core dumped)

As an attempted check, I did try to alloc.free(name.*) in both examples, and both identically reported error: index syntax required for slice type '[]const u8', implying to me they both identically receive indeed a []const u8
How can I fix these errors?

In the modified version, the function getNames is returning a pointer to a value stored on the stack, which is not allowed.
In zig, array types are somewhat confusing:

[N]u8 is a "array", a value type
[]u8 is a "slice", a pointer type. It is similar to struct {ptr: [*]u8, len: usize}
[*]u8 is a pointer, like *u8 but it allows array indexing syntax.

The type *[2]u8 can be implicitly casted to a slice []u8. You are then returning &new_names which is taking a pointer to a stack value. Data in the stack gets overwritten after you return from the function, and then everything gets messed up.
The solution is to return [][]const u8 instead of *[][]const u8.

Another thing to note:
try alloc.create([names.len][]const u8);

The length of array types must be known at comptime - so this call only works because names.len is known at comptime to be 2. If you were reading from a file, you wouldn't know the length at comptime and this wouldn't work. You likely want to use alloc.alloc() here to allocate a slice:
try alloc.alloc(u8, names.len);

and alloc.free() to free it

Another thing:
var new_names:[][]const u8 = undefined;
new_names = ...;

There is no reason to initialize a variable to undefined that you're immediately going to fill on the next line.
const new_names = ...;


Thanks for the explanation. I am getting the sense that I am not thinking about the task idiomatically... in more abstract languages I would happily have an N-array of various-length strings, all lengths unknown at compile time, resulting in an "arbitrary array of arbitrary strings". I think this is not a systems/memory way of thinking. Is there a "pattern" or idiomatic practice for this kind of use-case? Presumably a struct to represent a line, and a more complex "-list" type item?

(I have indeed played around with some of the changes you suggested, but so far not brought the code back to even a working-but-for-segfault state....)


I would happily have an N-array of various-length strings, all lengths unknown at compile time, resulting in an "arbitrary array of arbitrary strings" <

This is completely possible, but it has to be a slice of slices. [][]u8 is perfectly valid because it is a pointer to a contiguous array in memory of pointers.
Your second code block worked for me after: for(names.*) -> for(names), names:*[][]const u8 -> names:[][]const u8, for(names.*) -> for(names), alloc.destroy(names) -> alloc.free(names), !*[][]const u8 -> [][]const u8, return &new_names -> return new_names

.... I had done all that, except for destroy -> free because I had the item at names allocated using create ... I thought create had to entail use of destroy ? By not changing that, I was getting to a compile time error I didn't know what to do with .../lib/std/mem/Allocator.zig:113:28: error: ptr must be a single item pointer ...

There are decidedly still subtleties I need to wrap my head around, thank you for your guidance here :)

Create should mean use destroy - free happens to work fine here because the size and alignment is the same. You should switch create to alloc if you're going to use free, or alternatively return *[2][]const u8 from the fn which is the type create returns
